# How to return data from a column of a model .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, api

I would like to get the data of a column "type" of a Model object (Nature)

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<Nature>> FindAll()
    {
        using DBModelContext context = CreateNewContext();
        IEnumerable<Nature> nature = await context.Nature.Where(_ => _.Type); 
            return nature; 
    }
```

"Where" is not offered to me
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Most likely you're missing the `using System.Linq;` directive that tells the compiler to search that namespace for extension methods like `Enumerable.Where()`. As a side note, the underscore (`_`) is typically used to indicate a discard parameter: one that you maybe have to include in order to match the expected delegate signature, but you're not planning to use. In [C# 7, Discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards) were added as a language feature. You should avoid using the underscore for a variable you're actually planning to use.

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer, but still, I have an error "impossible to translate implicitly string to bool", I am a beginner maybe the answer is obvious but I don't find it

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is that you would like to return all values held in the `Type` column of your `Nature` table.

*As type information isn't available in the question, I'm assuming that `Nature.Type` is a `string` property.*

[`Queryable.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=net-6.0#system-linq-queryable-where-1(system-linq-iqueryable((-0))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-system-boolean)))))) takes a predicate argument that will filter the results of your table query. It doesn't look like that's what you are intending. Instead, try using [`Queryable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.select?view=net-6.0#system-linq-queryable-select-2(system-linq-iqueryable((-0))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-system-int32-1)))))):

```
IEnumerable<string> nature = await context.Nature.Select(nature => nature.Type);
```

You will then need to alter the return type of your method from `IEnumerable<Nature>` to `IEnumerable<string>` as you are only returning the value of the `Type` column, not the whole `Nature` object.